# How to change programmatically cellBottomLabel in JSQMessagesViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQMessagesViewController which loads an UICollectionView with JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell.

I am setting the cellBottomLabel text in collectionView:attributedTextForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath: and works great.

However, I need to refresh this text programmatically. If I reload the cell, everything works ok, but I don't want to do this, for performance considerations.

I tried to access cellBottomLabel from the cell:

```
JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.cellBottomLabel.text = @"TEST";
```

but this is not refreshing the text unless I scroll up and then back down (when the cell is reloaded).

Debugger shows cell.cellBottomLabel containing the desired text, but how can I force it to refresh on the cell display?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sure you are updating above on main thread but can you please check once?

Comment: What do you actually want ? Can you describe in detail

Answer (score 0):

Store your texts some where:

```
@interface SomeViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSArray<NSString *> *bottomTexts;

@end
```

When you get your new bottom text: first of all, check if you're on main thread, update array and then cell if possible.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSMutableArray<NSString *> *newBottomTexts = [self.bottomTexts mutableCopy];
    newBottomTexts[someIndex] = newText;
    self.bottomTexts = newBottomTexts;
    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellBottomLabel.text = newText;
});
```

But in case cell hadn't bottom text before it was updated you will not see next text because label's frame.size.height will be 0. In this case you should reload this single cell or resize it at least.

Comment: In case you have any problems, post sample - I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `setNeedsDisplay()`. It will force the repaint of the UI element to update text.